OpenCV Native libraries path not found in opencv 4.9.0
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()'
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:23)
    at temp.registerface.<init>(registerface.java:53)
    at temp.new_student.jButton2ActionPerformed(new_student.java:242)
    at temp.new_student$2.actionPerformed(new_student.java:121)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)

I wanted the face_module , so using visual studio i created that New jar file . And in Install folder // java i add that new jar file in my project . Now there is this error - that native libraries cannot be found , i pasted this error on AI chat and it told me native lib not found , nodefclass .
I also changed -Djava path with the path where my .dll files is present .
also i configured Cmake with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS = off
and made new jar file .
still no hope.
Added the x64/vc17/bin into environment variables
i have tried all this , please anyone have idea what wrong i am doing (i am using netbeans).

According to the opencv documentation for the Mat class there is no method with the name n_Mat.

@OldBoy - i have no idea , why is it coming
for reference - List images = new ArrayList<>();
this is where i am using Mat .
Also as i need bytedeco jar file and also opencv jar file . it is giving me import errors

please anyone , i need this for my project and i have to submit it in next week . Due to this my project dont even run.

There is not enough information provided for anyone to assist, beyond what I already explained. You need to find out which line of code is causing the error and update your question with the full details.

@OldBoy the Ai is telling it is not error in code but in the native libraries not being loaded

Then (assuming the Ai is correct) there must be something missing in your system that is required by the library or package that you are trying to use.

@OldBoy i literally dont know what else more does it want :(

Sorry I cannot offer any further suggestions. This issue would appear to be specific to opencv and its interface to Java. I suggest you try the opencv website for assisitance.

@OldBoy thanks to your advice i read all my code line to line and with the help of Ai assistant , i was able to remove some bugs.
Thank you for being there , you were my moral support - that i thought you know some answers.
Thanks.
